The emulator process for avd has terminated
новый ноут, свежая Студия с офф сайта. при попытке запустить эмулятор получаю the emulator process for avd has terminated
процессор ноута - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-13500H
ОС Win10
что уже попробовал:

включать/выключать виртуализацию в БИОСе
включать-выключать Hyper-V
переустанавливать Intel HAXM (он успешно установлен)

логи студии
2024-12-03 15:34:58,874 [ 501935]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 33 - C:\Disk\Program\Android\SDK\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_9_API_33
2024-12-03 15:34:58,905 [ 501966]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 33 - Android emulator version 35.2.10.0 (build_id 12414864) (CL:N/A)
2024-12-03 15:34:58,905 [ 501966]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 33 - Graphics backend: gfxstream
2024-12-03 15:34:58,905 [ 501966]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 33 - Found systemPath C:\Disk\Program\Android\SDK\system-images\android-33\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
2024-12-03 15:34:58,921 [ 501982]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 33 - Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
2024-12-03 15:34:58,921 [ 501982]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 33 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
2024-12-03 15:34:59,881 [ 502942]   WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_9_API_33 has terminated.
com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_9_API_33 has terminated.
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:134)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextCallable.call(ContextCallable.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

без понятия куда еще копать

Винду пора переустановить :) "The error 0xc0000135 probably occurs if there are some missing system files in your Windows."

@EugeneKrivenja так она свежая. + из командной строки эмулятор запускается.

как временное решение - смог запустить эмулятор через консоль (командную строки винды, НЕ в Студии)
cd C:\Disk\Program\Android\SDK\emulator
emulator -list-avds
emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_34 -no-snapshot-load

cd C:\Disk\Program\Android\SDK\emulator для навигации в папку к SDK
emulator -list-avds для получения названий созданных эмуляторов
emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_34 для запуска эмулятора, с учетом заранее настроенной при создании режима запуска (холодный или по последнему снимку)
параметр -no-snapshot-load для принудительного холодного старта
вопрос все еще открыт, т.к. при таком запуске эмулятор запускается в отельном окне, а чтобы подлкючить LayoutInspector он должен быть в окне студии (спасибо разрабам за такое "полезное" ноухау)
